# Turn each row of a csv of numbers into a separate list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file called sales_qty.csv with these contents:

25,64,23,45,14
12,82,19,34,63
54,22,17,43,35

I want to turn each row into a list.

So far I've tried this code:

```
import csv

with open('sales_qty.csv', 'r') as quantity:
    read = csv.reader(quantity)

    for row in read:
        lst1 = list(row)

    print(lst1)
```

The result was ['54', '22', '17', '43', '35'].
 So, the last row of the file gets assigned to the list. I'm triying to assign each row to its own list. But I don't know where to begin with that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea but you're overwriting `lst1` each time you read a row.  As a result, `lst1` will always show the last row.

One way to do it is to keep a list of lists:

```
results = []
for row in read:
  results.append(list(row))

print(results)
# [['25', '64', '23', '45', '14'], ['12', '82', '19', '34', '63'], ['54', '22', '17', '43', '35']]
```

You can print the whole list, as seen above.  Items in a list are also addressable by their index:

```
print(results[0])
# ['25', '64', '23', '45', '14']

print(results[1])
# ['12', '82', '19', '34', '63']

# and so on...
```

[Read up on Python lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

Comment: That was so simple! Thank you for taking the time to help someone just starting out with coding!